# I'm trying to make an applescript script that displays a text dialogue which I can enter in a URL and it opens it in my default browser.

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make an applescript script that displays a text dialogue which I can enter in a URL and it opens it in my default browser. Also, I'm trying to make it so there is an "http://" before the url so I can just type www.website.com. Here's the code I have so far.

```
display dialog "Website name" default answer ""
set x to text returned
open location "http:// x"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set dialogresult to display dialog "Website name" default answer ""
set x to text returned of dialogresult
open location "http://" & x
```

In future try to make your question more specific, ie why does

```
set x to "xyz"
log "http:// x"
```

not display "http:// xyz"?

But you might've still gotten some negative feedback for that.

Lets say you had

```
open location "http://www.excersise.com/x"
```

(just for the sake of argument), how can you expect the computer to know that one x represents a variable and the other doesn't?

If you have more questions just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want Safari to be the default browser. If you want a different browser simply change "Safari" to the name of the browser application; "Chrome" for example. Your almost there, just need to fix a bit of the coding/scripting. So here is the script your looking for. :)

```
display dialog "Website name" default answer ""
set x to the text returned of the result
tell application "Safari"
open location "http://" & x
end tell
```

You need to separate "http://" from the variable x or else AppleScript won't know the difference. By not putting " " around the x, it tells AS thats it's a variable and not regular text. And adding the & tells AS to add another piece of info to it. Which is useful when dealing with variables and dialog like in this case. Also you have to put:

```
set x to the text returned of the result
```

Not:

```
set x to text returned
```

It's just the way AS wants you to put it. Hope this helps a lot. Sorry for being 1 month late...

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to target a specific browser like Safari or Chrome, but rather just want to open the URL in your system default browser, ask Finder to open the location:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open location "http://google.com/"
end tell
```

… because it will pass the URL along to the system default browser rather than opening it itself.

Comment: `open location` is part of StandardAdditions.osax, the Finder is not needed at all.